# Next js cannot load

Tags: webpack, fonts, next.js, config

I am trying lo load in an eot from my custom npm into nextjs (with typescriot support), I get the folowing error.

```
./node_modules/@mybrand/themes/assets/fonts/operatorMono.eot
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:1)
```

My config is currently

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages({
  webpack: function (config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
      }
    })
    return config
  }
})
```

It works fine in create react app.

Comment: Did you restart your dev server after making the webpack changes in `next.config.js`?

Comment: yes multiple times :)